# Trying to include a <a href> on an echo on WordPress, but it doesn't work (PHP)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

PHP is not my best, so I've been having a hard time trying to include a  on a php slider. To make easier to understand what I'm talking about, please take a look at my website:

https://sooretamaemfoco.com.br/

You can notice that in the header there are a big slider on the left, and 4 mini sliders on the right. The ONLY place in my home page that doesn't have a hiperlink to the post when we click in the image is those big ones.

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvicO.jpg)

When you click on the picture, it doesn't have a href. The href is just on the title below. 
I've tried multiple ways to include a a href on the code, however it doesn't work.

Please take a look at the excerpt of code:

```
} elseif ($magbook_slider_design_layout=='small-slider'){
    echo '<div class="small-slider">';
    } else {
        echo  '<div class="multi-slider">';
    }
    echo  '<ul class="slides">';
    while ($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();
        $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id,'magbook_slider_image');
        $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
            echo '<li>';
            if ($image_attributes) {
                echo  '<div class="image-slider" title="'.the_title_attribute('echo=0').'"' .' style="background-image:url(' ."'" .esc_url($image_attributes[0])."'" .')">';
            }else{
                echo  '<div class="image-slider">';
            }
            echo  '<article class="slider-content">';
            if ($image_attributes != '' || $excerpt != '') {
                echo  '<div class="slider-text-content">';

                if($entry_format_meta_blog != 'hide-meta' ){
                    echo  '<div class="entry-meta">';
                        do_action('magbook_post_categories_list_id');
                    echo '</div> <!-- end .entry-meta -->';
                }

                $remove_link = $magbook_settings['magbook_slider_link'];
                    if($remove_link == 0){

                            echo '<h2 class="slider-title"><a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink()).'" title="'.the_title_attribute('echo=0').'" rel="bookmark">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2><!-- .slider-title -->';

                    }else{
                        echo '<h2 class="slider-title">'.get_the_title().'</h2><!-- .slider-title -->';
                    }

                    if ($excerpt != '') {
                        echo '<p class="slider-text">'.wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt(), true ).'</p><!-- end .slider-text -->';
                    }
                if($entry_format_meta_blog != 'hide-meta' ){
                    echo  '<div class="entry-meta">';
                    echo '<span class="author vcard"><a href="'.get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ).'" title="'.the_title_attribute('echo=0').'"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> ' .esc_attr(get_the_author()).'</a></span>';
                    printf( '<span class="posted-on"><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> %3$s</a></span>',
                                        esc_url(get_the_permalink()),
                                        esc_attr( get_the_time(get_option( 'date_format' )) ),
                                        esc_attr( get_the_time(get_option( 'date_format' )) )
                                    );

                    if ( comments_open()) { ?>
                            <span class="comments">
                            <?php comments_popup_link( __( '<i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> No Comments', 'magbook' ), __( '<i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 1 Comment', 'magbook' ), __( '<i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> % Comments', 'magbook' ), '', __( 'Comments Off', 'magbook' ) ); ?> </span>
                    <?php }
                    echo  '</div> <!-- end .entry-meta -->';
                }
                echo  '</div><!-- end .slider-text-content -->';
            }
            if( $magbook_settings['magbook_slider_button'] == 0 && $magbook_tag_text !='' ){
                echo '<div class="slider-buttons">';
                echo  '<a title='.'"'.the_title_attribute('echo=0'). '"'. ' '.'href="'.esc_url(get_permalink()).'"'.' class="btn-default">'.esc_attr($magbook_tag_text).'</a>';

                echo  '</div><!-- end .slider-buttons -->';
            }
            echo '</article><!-- end .slider-content --> ';
            echo '</div><!-- end .image-slider -->
            </li>';
```

The part that I've been trying to change is this one: `echo  '<div class="image-slider" title="'.the_title_attribute('echo=0').'"' .' style="background-image:url(' ."'" .esc_url($image_attributes[0])."'" .')">';`

Can somebody please give me a handle on this? It's highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:**

I've posted the whole code in the following link:
https://pastebin.com/QFMSMdZy

Comment: Try adding a <a href=""> tag before image-slider class this will ensure that image-slider is clickable. make sure you close </a> at the end of the image

Comment: I tried, it doen't work. :(